# Mongoose save() and find() are not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm Trying to make a functional page with mongodb and node.js using mongoose but when I need to use the mongoose functions "mongoose.save()" or "mongoose.find()" it just doesn't run, no error messages or anything like that.

I've went to atlas to see if there was anything wrong and everything seems all right

The relevant code of the router

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const Post = require('../Models/Post');
//ALL POSTS ARE SHOWN
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try{
    console.log('looking for all posts')
    const posts = await Post.find()
    res.json(posts)
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err})
    }
});
//A POST IS SEND
router.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    })
    await post.save()
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        res.json(data)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.json({ message: err })
    })
})
```

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema);
```

Everything i put before the save() or find() functions run, but when it comes to them, the app just stays there and doesn't do anything else.

Comment: I think it might be that you are exporting it as Posts, but requiring it as Post.

Comment: Tried it, but that don't seem to be the problem, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution for the problem but it doesn't have anything to do with the code i wrote, I'm not deleting this question because someone with a similar ISP as mine my might be running into the same issue; my ISP likes to from time to time rotate the IP addresses of it's users (I don't know why), and atlas has a security system that only allows the IP you put on their system to interact with your data base, the way to solve this is either put your new IP or set it to "ANYWHERE" so when you or your ISP change your IP address you still have access to your clusters.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it locally express router, and I believe the problem is with it, try this instead worked for me:

```
// Create a constant of express
const app = express();

// Then instead of router use app.
app.post('/', async (req, res)=>{
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    })
    await post.save()
    .then(data=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        res.json(data)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.json({ message: err })
    })
})
```

Comment: It is connected on a app.js, I didn't include that code on my question because I don't think that's where the error lies, but thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks, but the result it's the same

Comment: The last idea, the problem could be from the req body, so try saving hardcoded data.
like : title: 'Hello',
        description: 'something'

Comment: Also tried it, I'm working with post man, at this point I think It's a problem of atlas or something like that, but either way thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, I've Finally found the error, and it is not with in the code, my ISP switches my IP address from time to time, and mongodb uses your IP to allow or deny access to your data base network, so the way to fix it is to set your IP address to "ANYWHERE" and that's it, either way thank you so much for your help!